# Clients don't see each other on OpenVPN / IPFire

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, firewall, openvpn

I'm setting up an IPFire Server with OpenVPN and I want my clients to see each other. For this I've set up the OpenVPN Configuration via the webinterface of IPFire and started the server. The OpenVPN-subnet is `10.43.10.0/255.255.255.0`. I've enabled the checkbox `client-to-client` on the "Advanced Server Page". Furthermore I've pushed the route `10.43.10.0/255.255.255.0` via "Route push options".

Both clients can connect to the VPN, I can see that in the webinterface (CONNECTED) and on the clients. The first client is a windows PC that has the VPN-IP `10.43.10.18` assigned, another Linux client has `10.43.10.22`. If I make a ping to `10.43.10.1` from both clients, there is an answer. But I cannot ping nor telnet nor trace from one client to another. In fact "they don't see each other".

Just for testing purposes, I've disabled the firewalls on both machines, but no luck.

Should I add specific routes on both machines? If so, how would they look? I've already tried `route add 10.43.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.43.10.1 metric 1 if 15´ on the Windows PC with no luck (15 is the TAP-Windows adapter-Interface).

Or any suggestions what is missing?

Comment: Isn't ipfire designed to be hardened by default?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Thanks for the hint. I've tried to lower the security settings on ipfire for testing purposes, but it has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading on the internet I finally came up with a solution. I was missing the `topology subnet` entry in the `server.conf` file. Now the clients can see each other as expected.

This cannot be set via the webinterface (file is located under `/var/ipfire/ovpn/server.conf`).